# Make AutoHotKey's Edit This Script open scripts in Sublime Text 3

Tags: windows, script, autohotkey, text-editors, sublime-text-3

For years I've been using AutoHotKey to automate a few common tasks on my system using hotkeys. By default clicking `Edit This Script` on a running script (from the Windows system tray) opens Notepad. For quick edits this is fine, but it really gets in the way when trying to debug a script or write more advanced code.

How can I make `Edit This Script` open a proper text editor such as Sublime Text 3 instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AutoHotkeyScript\Shell\Edit\Command` registry key. I confirmed this on Windows 10 by using [Procmon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to monitor which keys were being used by AutoHotkey when *Edit This Script* is clicked on a running AHK script in the system tray.

---

### Run the reg file (recommended)

This is the recommended method because editing the Registry manually is more prone to errors, not to mention the usual disclaimer that editing the Windows Registry directly can be fatal for your computer if you don't know what you're doing.

Copy the below code into a file called `foo.reg` and run it, confirming any prompts that come up:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00 
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AutoHotkeyScript\Shell\Edit\Command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\Sublime Text 3\\sublime_text.exe\" \"%1\""
```

---

### Edit the registry manually

1. Open the Registry Editor by searching for "regedit" in the Start menu
2. Paste `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\AutoHotkeyScript\Shell` into the key search bar and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Right-click on the *Shell* key in the left pane and click `New` > `Key` and name it *Edit*
4. Right-click on the *Edit* key and click `New` > `Key`, naming it *Command*
5. In the *Command* key, double-click the *(Default)* value
6. Paste `C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "%1"` into the data field (replace with the path to your own preferred editor), and click `OK`

Reloading either the script or AHK itself isn't necessary - if you were successful, `Edit This Script` should now immediately open Sublime Text 3 (or whatever editor you replaced it with).

*PS. If you do use Sublime Text 3 to edit AHK scripts, you should also install the AutoHotkey package for syntax highlighting and more.*

Comment: This is a great answer. If you need more information or more detailed instructions, or want to see how to configure it for other popular AutoHotkey editors, see https://blog.danskingdom.com/Change-the-default-AutoHotkey-script-editor/